# google maps custom marker not displaying as my custom icon

Tags: python, google-maps

I'm using motionless in python (3.5) to build static map images.
I was having a hard time to create custom markers. But it seems like it's not so much the framework or my code, but the google maps API itself.

I can't figure out what's wrong with [my URL,](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=17&size=512x512&maptype=hybrid&markers=icon:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/havnar/sprites/master/ico/1ico%7C34.052230,%20-118.243680)while [this URL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=17&size=512x512&maptype=hybrid&markers=icon:http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico%7C34.052230,%20-118.243680), works.

I use this icon:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/havnar/sprites/master/ico/1.ico

While the stack overflow favicon just works:
http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico

Comment: What warning are you getting? Check your HTTP header

Comment: There is no warning, it's just not working. It show a yellow error "map error" messages in the top right corner (as you can see from my link). This lib seems to just build up an url (string) as well. So it's not clear to me why my icon shows up and the one from stack overflow does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with your icon file. I have re-saved the file out and uploaded to my own Github and it loads fine now:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=17&size=512x512&maptype=hybrid&markers=icon:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zensign/ico-test/master/favicon3.ico%7C34.052230%2C-118.243680

You can grab the working .ico file here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zensign/ico-test/master/favicon3.ico

Comment: I have a buch of those icons to fix, can you explain what was wrong with mine?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are saving them out, but I imported yours to this site: http://www.xiconeditor.com/ and then saved it back out. That fixed it.

Comment: @Havnar Hate to ask, but it would be customary to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your issue. Thanks.